# Communication between C++ and Javascript for WebGL

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, webgl, qwebview

My friend and I are trying to communicate between C++ and Javascript.
We want to render some spheres at a given position with WebGL embedded in a C++/Qt (version 5.6) application.

To do that, we use a `QWebView` which reads a HTML file with all the JS code for WebGL. This works well, we have a great high-level 3D renderer inside our application. **The problem is that the position is known by the C++ and has to be shared to the JavaScript**.

More precisely, the C++ knows the number of spheres we need to display and their position, and has to tell it to the Javascript side. What is the best way to do that?

Note : We tried to use Qt Canvas3D but it was too slow in comparison to the classic WebGL.

**EDIT 1 - After the first try**

I tried to do what you wrote and also read some examples (like this [one](http://blog.trumpton.org.uk/2015/09/qt-webengineview-communication-with.html)) but I cannot make it work.

I created a subclass of QWebEngineView where I do all my initializations and put my datas.

.h :

```
#ifndef WEBGLVIEW_H
#define WEBGLVIEW_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
#include <QtWebChannel/QtWebChannel>

class WebGLView : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INVOKABLE int getNumber();
    Q_PROPERTY(int num READ getNumber)
public:
    WebGLView(QWidget *parent = 0);

private  :
    QWebChannel*    m_channel;
};

#endif // WEBGLVIEW_H
```

.cpp :

```
#include "WebGLView.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDebug>

WebGLView::WebGLView(QWidget *parent) :
       QWebEngineView(parent)
{
    // Set up the communications channel
    //C++ to Java test
    m_channel = new QWebChannel(this);
    this->page()->setWebChannel(m_channel);
    m_channel->registerObject(QString("test"),this);

    QString path =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/test6.html";
    this->setUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path));
}

int WebGLView::getNumber()
{
    qDebug() << "getNumber";
    return 10;
}
```

At the beginning of the JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
...
var JSobject;
if (typeof qt != 'undefined') {new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
    JSobject = channel.objects.test;
} );
```

When I want to access the value :

```
if (typeof widget !== 'undefined') {
   var nspherefromc =  JSobject.getNumber;
} else {var nspherefromc = 50;}
```

When I run it :

- getNumber is called once, and it seems that it comes after a call to QWebChannel
- I have warning : Property 'num'' of object 'WebGLView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken!
- nspherefromc is the number of spheres that will be displayed. 50 are displayed, not 10.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT 2 - Second try**

I still cannot make it work.
I tried to add a new variable named more to see if a function is called or a if statement is entered :

```
var more = 0;
        if (typeof qt != 'undefined') {
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
                JSobject = channel.objects.test;
                more = 1000;
            }
            );
        }
```

I still have :

```
    if (typeof JSobject !== 'undefined') {
        nspherefromc =  JSobject.num;
    }
    else {nspherefromc = 50;}
    ...
    var spheresNum = nspherefromc + more;//Number of Spheres
```

When running it, I only have 50 spheres. The function in the QWebChannel is not called. I'm I suppose to call it myself ? And when ?
I also tried the more debug in the if(typeof qt != 'undefined') sttement and I got 1050 spheres.

**EDIT 3 - With a HTML Debugger**

```
    function init() {
        var JSobject;
        var nspherefromc = 0;
        if (typeof qt !== 'undefined') {
            new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
                JSobject = channel.objects.test;
                console.log(JSobject); //-> returns the object, I can access the functions and everything
                nspherefromc =  JSobject.num;
                console.log("in the function " + nspherefromc); //prints 5000, what i sent from C++
                more = 1000;
            }
            );
            console.log(JSobject); // prints undefined
        }
        console.log(JSobject); // prints undefined
        if (typeof JSobject !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("Yeaaaah"); //Not reached
            nspherefromc =  JSobject.num;
            nspherefromc + 1;
        }
        ...
        console.log("when loading " + nspherefromc + " (more is = to " + more); // nsphere = 0 , more = 0
            var spheresNum = nspherefromc + more;
```

Which means that outside of the function I cannot reach the JSobject anymore. Do you know why ?

**EDIT - In the end**
The openGL is already initialized when the data from the C++ is received. Therefore, the number of spheres displayed is not the one the C++ asked.

Comment: What version of Qt ?

Comment: Qt 5.6. Thanks for your question, I added it in the description.

Comment: I edited my answer following your edit.

Comment: From your edit number 3 : try to define `var JSobject` outside the function `init()`

Comment: Tried it too before putting it into init(). Same result...

Comment: Found something :
The problem comes from the order in which the functions are called.
I have to find the right order and understand when the function of the QWebChannel is called. If you know...

Comment: Yeah, don't forget that this is [asynchronous](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html) ;-)

Comment: Now it works. Thank you so much for everything :)

Comment: You are welcome, thanks for accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt5.6, if you want to make C++ part and JavaScript to communicate, the only way to do it is using [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html) on a [QWebEngineView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html). You do it this way in the `.cpp` file:

```
m_pView = new QWebEngineView(this);
QWebChannel * channel = new QWebChannel(page);
m_pView->page()->setWebChannel(channel);
channel->registerObject(QString("TheNameOfTheObjectUsed"), this);
```

Here, you just say that you register an object named `TheNameOfTheObjectUsed` that will be available on the JS side. Now, this is the part of code to use in the JS side :

```
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            // now you retrieve your object
            var JSobject = channel.objects.TheNameOfTheObjectUsed;
        });
```

And in your case, you want to retrieve the number of spheres, some positions, etc. So you need to have a method on the C++ side which returns a string, an integer, a long... This is what it looks like on the C++ side, in your `.h`:

```
Q_INVOKABLE int getNumberOfSpheres();
Q_PROPERTY(int NumberOfSpheres READ getNumberOfSpheres);
```

And now, you get the number of spheres like this on the JS side :

```
var nbSpheres = JSobject.NumberOfSpheres;
```

This is a very simple explanation, and I recommend you to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnvnTi6XafA) which was very useful to me. Also, you might want to read more about the [JavaScript API](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html) provided by QWebChannel, as well as the documentation about [QWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html);

Hope that helps!

---

**After your edit 1**

In your .h, you need to add (or change):

```
int m_pNumber;

Q_PROPERTY(int num READ getNumber WRITE setNumber NOTIFY numChanged)

Q_INVOKABLE void setNumber(int number); // add this function to the cpp file as well

//add a signal for NOTIFY
signals:
    void numChanged();

public slots:
    void numHasChanged();
```

In your constructor in the .cpp :

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(numChanged()), this, SLOT(numHasChanged()));
```

And in the cpp itself :

```
void WebGLView::setNumber(int number)
{
    m_pNumber = number;
    emit numChanged();
}

int WebGLView::getNumber()
{
    return m_pNumber;
}


void WebGLView::numHasChanged()
{
     // do anything here
}
```

**And very important in the JS side :**

First, be careful, you copied some code without checking it, so I think you meant :

```
if (typeof JSobject !== 'undefined')
```

instead of

```
if (typeof widget !== 'undefined')
```

And then :

```
var nspherefromc =  JSobject.num; // this is ok
var nspherefromc =  JSobject.getNumber; // this is NOT ok
```

Now, whenever you'll change your variable `num` in JS, a signal will be emitted (`numChanged`) and you will be able to get the value in the corresponding slot with a `getNumber()`.

Comment: That helps a lot ! Thank you !
I started watching the video and I'm now going to try it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to help :) if you have any other question when you try it, don't hesitate!

Comment: I'm blocking...

I did like you did, I even read other examples that work, but I still have trouble.
How do I do to show some more code to you ? Comment or edit ?

Comment: Mmh just edit your post with what you have tried so far (since you need 20 rep to talk in chat)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'm trying it right now. Quick question : Why do we need m_pNumber if we already have a Q_PROPERTY num ?

Comment: That is another good question but you can read it from here ;) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html. To make it very simple, `num` is for the JS side, and `m_pNumber` is for the C++ side.

Comment: I still have the problem. I edited, I don't know if you got the notification.

Comment: There's a typo, it is `if (typeof qt !== "undefined")` (a `=` missing) but I don't know if it is the problem. How do you debug your program?

Comment: I still have the problem. For C++ part it is the qt creator debugger, for the JS and don't really know how to do. I have some output in the qt creator console but all the console.log() do not work.

Comment: Thanks, it is reall usefull :)
I'm editing since I got new results !