# screen object in JavaScript not available in a QWebEnginePage

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I have a Qt application that launches Webviews using `QWebChannel`.

In these views, I have the JavaScript doing some stuff in order to position/resize the window depending on the screen size. The `screen` object is supposed to give this kind of information. ([screen doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp))

But in my `QWebEnginePage`, the screen object is empty during the whole loading process.

If I put a listener on a button to get `screen.height` somewhere on the page, now it works.

```
//js local file called in html head

//screen = {}
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  //screen = {}
  new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel) {
    //screen = {}
    //stuff
    channel.object.myClass.show(function(res){ //Qt function that calls the show() method of the QWebEngineView
      //screen = {}
    });

  });

  document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("height:" + screen.height); // screen: 1440
  });
});
```

So my question is, how can I access `screen` values at some point in my JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that at the moment you are trying to access your `screen` object, it is not available. Indeed, your HTML file will be loaded directly, but other objects such as JavaScript objects/programs or style sheets (e.g. CSS files) will be loaded *asynchronously*.

It is explained in the documentation of [QWebEnginePage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html):

> The html is loaded immediately; external objects are loaded asynchronously.

Thus, while your page is not loaded, you can't access this property. However, you can access it once the page is loaded, like you are doing actually with a listener on a button. Another way to get these properties is to define `Q_INVOKABLE` methods in your class in order to retrieve them in the C++ side ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545104/5653461)).

Comment: Isn't what the `load` event is supposed to do ? Be triggered after the document and its dependent resources have been loaded ? 

I just migrated from `QWebPage`, where I suppose external objects were loaded synchronously.

Yes I could use a `Q_INVOKABLE` method in order to retrieve these values. Just being sure I can't do the same as before.

Comment: The global javascript variable "window" fires the "load" event, then `QWebEnginePage` emits the signal `loadFinished()` and only after that you can retrieve the properties

Comment: I just tried reading `screen` values after the `loadFinished()` signal, and `screen` is still not available. In fact, `loadFinished()` is emitted before the JavaScript event `load`, even before `DomContentLoaded`.
I will follow your advice and implement `Q_INVOKABLE` methods to get these values. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh, I was certain about the `loadFinished()`... My time to learn something I guess ^^ good luck!